# Zxing scanned result how to paste on editText

Tags: android

Hello I want to thank you in advance for your answers. My problem is I am using Zxing to scan qr codes. And I want to paste the scan value on the my edit text at Login Activity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.logizard.logizard_go.R;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScanResult extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{


    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_result);

        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        // Do something with the result here
        // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        // Log.v("tag", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

        Login.editTextUser.setText(rawResult.getText());

        onBackPressed();



        // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
        //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }



    }
```

This is the sample code that I use but every time I use the button for scan nothing happens.

Comment: Did you want to scan result only?

Comment: you are missing `setResultHandler` of `mScannerView`.

Comment: What is `Login`?

Comment: What I want is that if I scan the QR code the result will be pasted on the editText. if I use this code it will show the result on textView. Note  LoginScan is different Java class from Login that I posted. Basically what I want is that the scanned results will be paste on the  "editTextUser" on the Login java class
LoginScan.textView4.setText(rawResult.getText());

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you have a `Login`(Activity) that open the `ScanResult`(Activity) and you want to return the value of the scanned to `Login`

I suggest to you to look this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), but also maybe you could move the handlingscan part of your code to `Login` activity

```
... implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        editTextUser.setText(rawResult.getText());
    }
}
```

**BETTER do like that**

**in `Login`**

```
static final int GET_SCANNED = 1;
...
private void openScanResult(){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ScanResult.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, GET_SCANNED);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == GET_SCANNED) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("scanned");
            editTextUser.setText(result)
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
           //Write your code if there's no result
        }
     }
  }
```

**in `ScanResult`**

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("scanned",rawResult.getText());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for your answer I will now try the codes that you shared to me. I only have 2 questions. 

1. But also maybe you could move the handlingscan part of your code to Login activity? 
  - Do I need to transfer that on my Login activity.


2. Basically Sir there are two editText that I want to paste the data with. editTextUser and editTextPass both on Login Activity. how can I do that Sir Thank you so much I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Sir is there any way that I can send you my codes? for you to check I'm trying my best to understand and analyze your answer but I cant understand and I'm confuse where to put the codes on Login activity. I wish you will notice my concern Thank you so much!